# Why is my AngularJS $resource caching its results?

Tags: angularjs

When i click on a delete button on a detail view of a user record, the record gets deleted and i'm routed back to the main list view ('main).  But the list view still has the deleted record unless i refresh the page.  It appears that Users.query() call is being cached from the previews list view.

Here is the service:

```
service.factory('Users', function ($resource) {
console.debug('getting users from web service ...');
return $resource('http://localhost:8080/ClearsoftDemoBackend/webresources/clearsoft.demo.users', {}, {
    query: {
        method: 'GET', 
        isArray: true,
        cache: false 
    },
    get: {
        method: 'GET', 
        cache: false 
    }
});
});
```

And here is the controller:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Users, $location) {
        console.debug('entering main controller ...');
        $scope.users = Users.query();
        $scope.sortField = 'lastName';
        $scope.reverseSort = true;
        $scope.gotoAdd = function () {
            $location.path('/add/');
        };
    })
.controller('DetailCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, UserDetail, $location) {
        $scope.user = UserDetail.find({}, {'id': $routeParams.id});
        $scope.clickEdit = function () {
            $location.path('/edit/' + $routeParams.id);
        };
        $scope.clickDelete = function () {    
            UserDetail.delete({}, {'id': $scope.user.id});
            console.debug('deleted user ...' + $scope.user);
            $location.path('/main');   
        };
    })
```

Comment: Are you sure the server isn't caching it or sending back an 'unmodified' response?  Do you see anything in the network tab in chrome dev tools for the request?

Comment: If so, consider changing your 'get' to a 'post' to indicate that it should not be cached

Comment: For some when i click delete, the  UserDetail.delete() service is getting called after the Users.query() service.  So the delete is working, but i'm already looking at the main list again before the delete completes (which is why the item is still in the list in the main view).

Comment: After i click delete and we go back to the MainCtrl, this call doesn't seem to fire:  scope.users = Users.query();

Comment: If _scope.users = Users.query()_ line has role to bind your list view, try to inject _Users_ service into your _DetailCtrl_ controller and  BIND AGAIN your list view in your $scope.clickDelete function after the UserDetail.delete service...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to handle the delete() call as a promise so that the subsequent call to retrieve users doesn't fire before the delete is completed:

```
$scope.user.$delete().then(function () {
                console.debug('deleted user ...');
                $scope.deleted = true;
                $scope.error = false;
                $location.path('/main/');
            }, function () {
                console.debug('Failed to delete user ...');
                $scope.error = true;
                $scope.deleted = false;
            });
```

Comment: Nice, I totally forgot this potential problem :D Congratulations! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code and problem correctly, the main problem is that your list view isn't refreshing it's content after the delete.

Theorerically, you must after calling the delete service in your function GET the data again.
Try this:

```
//include Users service to this controller to use UsersQuery to 'refresh the view'
    .controller('DetailCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, UserDetail, Users, $location) { 
                $scope.user = UserDetail.find({}, {'id': $routeParams.id});
                $scope.clickEdit = function () {
                    $location.path('/edit/' + $routeParams.id);
                };
                $scope.clickDelete = function () {    
                    UserDetail.delete({}, {'id': $scope.user.id});
                    console.debug('deleted user ...' + $scope.user);
                    $scope.users = Users.query(); //get the refreshed data after deleting operation
                    $location.path('/main');   
                };
            })
```

**EDITED**
You can maybe put the services in one common controller to avoid such problems...

```
        .controller('CommonCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, UserDetail, Users, $location) { 

//From Main Ctrl
console.debug('entering main controller ...');
        $scope.users = Users.query();
        $scope.sortField = 'lastName';
        $scope.reverseSort = true;
        $scope.gotoAdd = function () {
            $location.path('/add/');
        };

//from DetailsCtrl
 $scope.user = UserDetail.find({}, {'id': $routeParams.id});
                    $scope.clickEdit = function () {
                        $location.path('/edit/' + $routeParams.id);
                    };
                    $scope.clickDelete = function () {    
                        UserDetail.delete({}, {'id': $scope.user.id});
                        console.debug('deleted user ...' + $scope.user);
                        $scope.users = Users.query(); //get the refreshed data after deleting operation
                        $location.path('/main');   
                    };
                })
```

I don't know your app structure, but experience with AngularJS told me that it's OK to seperate CRUD operations of some object into different services, but you must call them in the one controller when you manipulate with the same type object(s) which is(are) manipulated by that services...

This is the best structure of angular app organization: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure#a-better-structure-and-foundation. In other words, for each manipulated model create controler, service and view (For example, for model *STUDENT* create *StudentService* for your CRUD operations, *StudentCtrl*, where you will create functions to call the services/factories, and a view for Student )

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help.  Wouldn't it be refreshing the users list to the wrong scope anyway?

Comment: Ah you are right... But why do you seperate it in diferrent controllers?? There is no need to do that... Include the same services that you use in only one controller and you will get the data in the right scope?

Comment: I could probably make that work, but isn't it a pretty common pattern to have one controller for each view?  Why doesn't Users.query() get called every time the main view (and its associated controller) is loaded?

Comment: I edited my answer. I think Users.query does not call because of some tricky part in location.path() ...

Comment: i just had to add a ".then( ...." after the call to the delete service and change the location within that.